# No sound with mpg123 or mplayer at boot

Tags: boot, audio, cron

What I want to do : at boot, start a playlist on a headless RBPi A+ through the headphones jack using mpg123.

I Wrote a shell script targeting mpg123:

```
#!/bin/bash
# see if (and when) my script was run : 
date >> /home/MY_USER_NAME/date.txt
# infinitely and randomly play a playlist using mpg123
/bin/mpg123 -v -o alsa --mono -Z 0 /home/MY_USER_NAME/music/lofi-grl/*.mp3
```

and added this line to crontab using `sudo crontab -e` :
`@reboot sh /home/MY_USER_NAME/start.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1`

In short, the script is working fine from the terminal, but partially when run by cron : the file date.txt is there, but there is no sound, and if I do `top | grep mpg123` there is no mpg123 process.

Everything in the cron.log file is fine except the last line :

```
000000+143478  00:00.00+01:02:27 --- 100=100  32 kb/s  104 B acc    0 clip p+0.000^M> 000008+143470  00:00.18+01:02:27 --- 100=100  32 kb/s  104 B acc    0 clip p+0.000
main: [src/mpg123.c:839] error: Deep trouble! Cannot flush to my output anymore!
```

I tried using `crontab -e` instead of `sudo crontab -e`, didn't work. I tried adding mpg123 to sudoers `ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mpg123` to sudoers like suggested in an other thread but nothing works. I even tried using /etc/rc.local which didn't work either.
I am really pulling my hair on this one ! Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I (finally) figured out :
1/ Although you can omit it when using the terminal it You **have** to specify which device you want mpg123 to use in the form -a hw:x,y when run from cron task (in my case `hw:1,0` which is headphones jack output o, the RBPi)

2/ mpg123 can't operate until the sound device is ready (obviously) which is not the case when the @reboot event is fired. the solution was to wait for 20 seconds before running the script : `@reboot sleep 20 && sh /path/to/myscript.sh`

Now I have to figure out how to run this script exactly the moment the audio device is ready.

Comment: `"have to figure out how to run this script exactly the moment the audio device is ready"`. You won't be able to do that with `cron` - it's not *"resource aware"*. You ***might*** be able to cobble a `systemd` unit, but be preared to spend time on this!